# exam portal questions and answers cache procedure

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching, iframe

I am a learner and trying to develop a webportal for online mocktests.
in this portal, after being redirected to the mocktest page, the exam page look something like... a php page having a
1. timer on top
2. two iframes - one on left and one on right - src is php file

The left iframe would contain all buttons displaying questions number.
Right frame would display the question and answer options as radio buttons.

The problem is with caching the questions. Once I check a radio button of questionx, navigate to some other question and come back to the questionx again, the checked option is not visible.. which is to say that the question is again queried from database and displayed afresh. I want already visited questions, selected answers to be cached.
How should I accomplish this?

[the mocktest web page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhWNP.png)

code for mocktest web page include the frames like below -

```
    <!-- questions numbers left div -->
    <div class="left">
    <Iframe id="frame1" name="iframe1" src="Questions/QuantitativeAptitude.php" ></Iframe>

    </div> <!--div  classs=left -->

    <!-- display question right div-->
    <div class="right">

    <Iframe id="frame2" name="iframe2" src="Questions/displayQuestion.php"></Iframe>

    </div> <!--div  classs=right -->
```

QuantitativeAptitude.php contains a form, from which a buttom is created

```
    <form name="frm2" >
    <input id="questionButton" type="button" name="questionNum" value="<?php echo $questionNum;?>" onclick="parent.hello(this.form.questionNum.value);">
    </form>
```

javascript function defined in the parent page i.e., mocktest page pass the clicked/selected question number to displayQuestion.php file

in displayQuestion.php file, question is retrieved using _GET, query database, display question and answer options through a form.

```
<FORM method="POST" >

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="1" NAME="theAnswer" onclick="return displayAnswer(value)">
<span class="answerOptions">1. <?php echo $Option1; ?><BR><BR> </span>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="2" NAME="theAnswer" onclick="return displayAnswer(value)">
<span class="answerOptions">2. <?php echo $Option2; ?><BR><BR></span>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="3" NAME="theAnswer" onclick="return displayAnswer(value)">
<span class="answerOptions">3. <?php echo $Option3; ?><BR><BR></span>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="4" NAME="theAnswer" onclick="return displayAnswer(value)">
<span class="answerOptions">4. <?php echo $Option4; ?><BR><BR></span>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="5" NAME="theAnswer" onclick="return displayAnswer(value)">
<span class="answerOptions">5. <?php echo $Option5; ?><BR><BR></span>
</FORM>
```

to capture the checked radio button in order to store in database I tried two methodologies -
1. javascript
2. jquery

method 1: javascript

```
 function displayAnswer(answer){
    var optionSelected = answer;
    alert (optionSelected);
    return true;
 }
```

With this methodology, I could see the alert message stating the selected option only for few questions, not all. Also, using javascript, it will be tedious to pass this "optionSelected " variable to another php file where the database would be updated with user selected answer.
**NOTE:**I placed a breakpoint in the above javascript code, using developer tool(F12). As obvious, code did not break for those questions where the alert message was not seen.

method 2:jquery
here I have downloaded jquery-1.12.4.min.js into my xampp project js folder and included into the php file. After, writing jquery, few of the questions itself stopped displaying.

```
    <script>
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var value = $("form input[type='radio']:checked").val();
        alert("Value of Changed Radio is : " +value);
    });
    </script>
```

Using this jquery, only question 1, 2, 3, 7 are displayed out of 70(in 5 tabs) questions in mocktest. I do not understand why only these questions are displayed and why remaining questions are not displayed.

[database sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrJaS.png)

From the data shown in attached image, question 4, 5, 6, 8 popup alert message when radio button is checked.

Comment: Please describe the flow of what your php is currently doing. Describe as in what happens when you click  a button. When do you query the question or how do you currently save the answer.

Comment: You have to show us the pattern of your code so we know how to help you

Comment: And in what I see, when someone checks an answer the page does nothing, no php query or ajax call is made. So I suggest you use the jquery ajax method to save your answers in the database then you also run an `if` and `else` statement to make an answered questions checked when the page is loading. Please show us some code and the structure of your database also so you can get the correct answer

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots, code and description. Please do mention if anything missing to make the point.